# Не могу запустить java.exe из командной строки (cmd)

Tags: java, bat

Не могу запустить java.exe из командной строки (cmd).
В наличии ноутбук с Windows XP (32 bit) c установленным JDK Update 144.
Запускаю `bat` файл:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BINDIR=%~dp0
CD /D "%BINDIR%"
java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar crt.jar 
PAUSE
```

> java не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или внутренним файлом

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Добавьте целиком текс вашего БАТ файла в вопрос. Скорее всего у вас просто не прописаны переменные среды. Укажите путь к файлу `java.exe` напрямую

Comment: переменную окружения установили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в переменную среды `Path` путь до вашей `JDK` и можно добавить переменную среды `JAVA_HOME`(если такой еще нет).
Путь до `JDK` может выглядеть примерно так: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin`.

Альтернативным вариантом будет просто напрямую указать путь до файла `java.exe`.
В вашем случае вызов мог бы выглядеть примерно так:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar crt.jar
```