# Как в командной строке Windows 10 исполнить файл .bat, запускающий другой файл .jar?

Tags: java, bat, jar, командная-строка, файловые-пути

Требуется исполнить файл `jar`, для чего запустить на исполнение файл `bat` со скриптом. Указал в строке команду к исполняемому файлу `Test9`:

> f:\Program_training......\Test9>java.exe -jar Test9.jar

Но получил ошибку:

> "java.exe" не является внутренней или внешней
> командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Нашел переменную `Path` и добавил путь до установленной Java:

> c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\

Но не помогло. То же уведомление получил, когда попробовал ввести непосредственно в командной строке нотацию `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java -jar Test9.jar`.

Как можно решить задачу?

Comment: Все это понятно, только вот непонятно зачем jar файл запускать из bat файла.

Comment: @Roman C, здесь уж не от меня зависит: такое задание с предзаданными файлами

Comment: Подробнее можно? Что за задание? Какими предзаданными файлами?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу запустить java.exe из командной строки (cmd)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752929/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-java-exe-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Консоль по ключевому (первому) слову ищет в PATH исполняемый файл, и выполняет. Вам нужно вводить не само имя файла, а его PATH-алиас. `java -jar Test9.jar` должно сработать, если `Test9.jar` лежит в открытой директории консоли.

Comment: Ответ помог: программа заработала, для чего потребовалось перезапустит командную строку. В итоге результат достигнут. Я перешел в папку с файлом и инициировал команду `java -jar Test9.jar`